# disply the current week start and end date

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to display the Current week in `UINavigationBar` and then click on Next or Previous button to display the Previous week or Next week

Example:

```
July 22 - July 28
July 29 - Auguest 4
```

Comment: according to the documentation of `NSDateFormatter` it seems it will be a manual work for you.

Comment: This is really a job for NSCallendar.

Comment: Well the answerer below has both of your suggestions so hurrah for teamwork!

Answer (score 1):

To get first date of the week you can do something like this :

```
- (NSDate *)firstDayOfWeekFromDate:(NSDate *)date {
    CFCalendarRef currentCalendar = CFCalendarCopyCurrent();
    NSDateComponents *components = [CURRENT_CALENDAR components:DATE_COMPONENTS  fromDate:date];
    [components setDay:([components day] - ([components weekday] - CFCalendarGetFirstWeekday(currentCalendar)))];
    //[components setDay:(CFCalendarGetFirstWeekday(currentCalendar))];
    [components setHour:0];
    [components setMinute:0];
    [components setSecond:0];
    CFRelease(currentCalendar);
    return [CURRENT_CALENDAR dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

After getting first week of the day you can calculate days as suggested in above answer by @vikas
 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSDate * selectedDate = [NSDate date];


-(IBAction)Week_CalendarActionEvents:(id)sender{

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDate *nextDate;

if(sender==Week_prevBarBtn)  // Previous button events 
    [offsetComponents setDay:-7];
else if(sender==Week_nextBarBtn) // next button events 
    [offsetComponents setDay:7];

nextDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:selectedDate options:0];

selectedDate = nextDate;
[selectedDate retain];

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:selectedDate];
NSInteger week = [components week];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM YYYY"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];
[formatter release];
[Week_weekBarBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,Week %d",stringFromDate,week]];
```

}

Comment: This code will get you a difference of 7 days not from week start to week end